# How to view embeded html5 video in localhost webpage(PC) from android webview

Tags: android, ios, html, audio, video

I have designed a html+jsp webpage with mp3 audios and mp4 videos and run that on my browser using tomcat server

```
 http://localhost:8084/neclogin/main.jsp
```

I also accessed it from my real device android (connected to PC via hotspot) by placing URL on browser.It worked well for audio and video.

```
 http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/neclogin/web/main.jsp
```

But when i tried to access it from an android app which i created

It connects so good and also i could play all audio files in it.But when i tried to play the videos ,I could not.

**THE CODE FOR AUDIO**

```
  <audio controls>
                         <source src="audio/song1.MP3" type="audio/mpeg">
                         Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag.
  </audio>
```

**THE CODE FOR VIDEO**

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video/Nenjam Pesuthe-title song.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/Nenjam Pesuthe-title song.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="video/Nenjam Pesuthe-title song.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object data="video/Nenjam Pesuthe-title song.mp4" width="320" height="240">
  <embed src="video/Nenjam Pesuthe-title song.swf" width="320" height="240">
  </object> 
</video>



 **`FOR MORE DETAIL`**

    1)windows 7
    2)NETBEANS IDE WITH APACHE TOMCAT SERVER 8.03
    3)**Both connected via wifi hotspot on my mobile**
    4)path to my main.jsp is `C:\Users\dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\neclogin\web\main.jsp`
    5)path to my tomcat server installed is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.3`
```

Comment: you don't say what's not working with video. do you get audio but no video? if so check out hardware acceleration etc at https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414

Comment: @Offbeatmammal yes i get audio but not video.I have added harware accelaration in manifest file.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal actually i could see the video player in android while accessing jsp server.But no video over there.